# How do I compare two columns and delete the not overlapping elements?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two columns in two data frames, where the longer one includes all elements of the other column. Now I want to delete elements in the longer column that do not overlap with the other, together with the corresponding row. I identified the "difference" using:

`diff <- setdiff(gdp$country, tfpg$country)`

and I tried to use two FOR loops to get this done:

```
for (i in 1:28) { for(j in 1:123) {if(diff[i] == gdp$country[j]) {gdp <- gdp[-c(j),]}}}
```

where 28 is the number of rows I want to delete (length of diff) and 123 is the length of the longer column. This does not work, the error message:

```
Error in if (diff[i] == gdp$country[j]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So how do I fix this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much.

---

I have a data frame called "gdp" here:

```
  country  wto   y1990   y1991   y1992

Austria 1995  251540  260197  265644

Belgium 1995  322113  328017  333038

Cyprus 1995   14436   14537   15898

Denmark 1995  177089  179392  182936

Finland 1995  149584  140737  136058

France 1995 1804032 1822778 1851937
```

There are 123 rows.
I would like to delete rows with country names specified in another vector:

```
diff ["Austria","China",...,"Yemen"]
```

Comment: Can you post minimal input data and expected output so we can help with working code?

Comment: Just updated with example... Not sure if it's helpful :) Thanks!!

Comment: If you have: `countriesToDelete <- c('Austria', 'China', 'Yemen')`, you can then filter the original df as follows: `gdp[!gdp$country %in% countriesToDelete, ]`.

Comment: This is perfect. Solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a better way!  What you're describing is the equivalent of a left join, or inner join.  But in R the way to achieve it is using the merge command:

```
## S3 method for class 'data.frame'
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
  by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
  sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"),
  incomparables = NULL, ...)
```

In your case:

```
merge(gdp, tfpg, by = intersect('country', 'country'))
```

E.g.

```
x = data.frame(foo = c(1,2,3,4,5), bar=c("A","B","C","D","E"))
y = data.frame(baz = c(6,7,8,9), bar=c("A","C","E","F"))
z = merge(x,y,by=intersect('bar','bar'))
```

gives

```
  bar foo baz
1   A   1   6
2   C   3   7
3   E   5   8
```

Comment: `intersect('country', 'country')` seems unnecessary (just `by = "country"` should do)

Comment: Works! Thanks!!! The two data frames do not have the same columns so merge() merges the columns in tfpg into gdp, but I can simply just delete those. And by = "country" works as well.